# Same module different casing. Why?

Tags: powershell

There is a bit of a problem going on with minikube and docker-machine on windows, determining if hyper-v module is available. For more information:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2634
- https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4424

but this is not essential.

What is, that on two Windows 10 machines, both up-to-date, both with WMF 5.1 (PSVersion 5.1.16299.251) When running `Get-Command hyper-v\get-vm` we get different results.

Let me demonstrate:

[image]

[image]

The difference is that the module name differs. It's "hyper-v" vs "Hyper-V".
I compared byte-for-byte files inside `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Hyper-V`. They are the same, and the path name have the same casing.

So why is the difference?

Comment: Compare `(Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Hyper-V).Name` on the two machines :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen as I specified in the question above both are the same, they read `Hyper-V`. *the path name have the same casing*

Comment: `Get-Command hyper-v\Get-VM | fl * ` have a look at the fields DLL and helpfile. Are the assembly DLLs the same in the Gac ? Are the Helpfile identicals ?

Comment: @JPBlanc on one of the machine the HelpFile field has just the help file name, on the other it's full path. I'll do more comparing and report back.

Comment: The dlls are the same. The help file is absent on one of the machines. (The one that does not have the full path in the HelpFile property)

Comment: Removing the help file from the other machine too does not change the capitalisation.

Comment: How did you import the module? See answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely caused by how the module is imported:

```
Import-Module Hyper-v
(Get-Command hyper-v\get-vm).Module.Name
```

The previous code will report the module as `Hyper-v`.

[image]

You can avoid this problem with performing the query as follows:

```
@(Get-Module -ListAvailable hyper-v).Name | Get-Unique
```

You will get the casing that is consistent between all version of PowerShell and Build versions of Windows.

[image: PowerShell 6.0.0 hyper-v module]
Expected:
[image: PowerShell 5.1 hyper-v module]
But this is sometimes seen:
[image: Sometimes this is seen]

Note: There are two libraries installed for the modules, which you can see with `Get-Module -ListAvailable`. Maybe these versions or the Windows build or release version differs? At least, this information is relevant since Windows 10, as they are not fixed anymore. They might help with pinpointing (added comment).