# Golang invoking PowerShell.exe always returns ASCII characters

Tags: powershell, go

I am using PowerShell from an application written in Go, but am unable to get it to return non-ASCII characters. At first I used go-powershell, but experience the same issue: https://github.com/gorillalabs/go-powershell/issues/10 and now using a slightly more basic approach:

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
)

type PowerShell struct {
        powerShell string
}

func New() *PowerShell {
        ps, _ := exec.LookPath("powershell.exe")
        return &PowerShell{
                powerShell: ps,
        }
}

func (p *PowerShell) Execute(args ...string) (stdOut string, stdErr string, err error) {
        args = append([]string{"-NoProfile", "-NonInteractive"}, args...)
        cmd := exec.Command(p.powerShell, args...)

        var stdout bytes.Buffer
        var stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr

        err = cmd.Run()
        stdOut, stdErr = stdout.String(), stderr.String()
        return
}

func main() {
        posh := New()
        stdout, stderr, err := posh.Execute("$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding; (Get-VMSwitch).Name")

        fmt.Println(stdout)
        fmt.Println(stderr)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
}
```

but the same happens. Instead of gettting `Przełąś`, it returns `Przelas`. This will result in issues when further in the code a VM is created using this Virtual Switch name. It does not get recognized and errors.

Note: `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding;` did not have any effect. It does get changed, but the result remains the same.

Note 2: invoking the same command directly from the command prompt does NOT have issues: `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive $OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding; (Get-VMSwitch).Name")` or even `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive (Get-VMSwitch).Name")`. In other words, it does this only from Go when using `exec.Command`.

Note 3: this is for fixing an issue with a virtual machine driver when it comes to the localized names. Yes, it could work with an GUID (`.Id`) instead, but this issue persists in different parts of the system.

Comment: Just out of interest: why write it in go and not in PowerShell. For the task at hand, PowerShell seems to be the best tool and spawning commandline tools and parsing it's output is a very unreliable method.

Comment: See note 3: it is part of a driver for docker/machine. Sure, no problem with writing it in PowerShell commands ... but the driver has to wrap these commands for higher level interaction using another command. Note: other issues have existed due to parsing, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765816/same-module-different-casing-why/49788125#49788125 but this was a choice and several projects rely on this now.

Comment: HAve you tried using the `bytes.Runes()` function? You seem to be using bytes buffers, which are essentially ASCII characters. To interpret them as unicode, just passing them through [the `bytes.Rune()` func](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Runes) might just fix it

Comment: Write a text file with your program that contains the PowerShell command you want to execute, and check what encoding it uses.

Comment: Note 4: Modifying the OutputEncoding had no effect. Setting it to UTF8 or other codepage would result in the same output for Get-VMSwitch.

Comment: Is "Note 4" in response to my answer? Are you saying that updating `[Console]::OutputEncoding` as I demonstrated has no effect?

Comment: FYI, updated my answer to embed the test string directly into the program and to print out the current value of `[Console]::OutputEncoding` before printing out the test string. If you could provided the value of that variable on your system, it may help in troubleshooting.

Comment: It seems to be related to how Non-Interactive mode handles `$OutputEncoding`. However, when invoked from the Command Prompt as such it works, but not when invoked from `exec.Command`. Using `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8` directly works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man, Powershell is interesting. This was mostly the result of a bunch of trial and error.

Basically, you want to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, not capture it.

However, to clean up after yourself, it doesn't hurt to set it back to it's original value. I haven't fully wrapped my head around it, but the change persists through multiple `exec()` calls.

Here's an example:

```
<... everything else is as above ...>

func main() {
        posh := New()

        fmt.Println("With encoding change:")
        stdout, stderr, err := posh.Execute(
                "$test = \"Przełąś\"\n" +
                "$old = [Console]::OutputEncoding\n" +
                "[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8\n" +
                "[Console]::OutputEncoding\n" +
                "$test\n" +
                "[Console]::OutputEncoding = $old")
        fmt.Println(stdout)
        fmt.Println(stderr)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Without encoding change:")
        stdout, stderr, err = posh.Execute(
                "$test = \"Przełąś\"\n" +
                "[Console]::OutputEncoding\n" +
                "$test")
        fmt.Println(stdout)
        fmt.Println(stderr)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./exec-powershell.exe
With encoding change:


BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : False
CodePage          : 65001

Przełąś




Without encoding change:


IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : IBM437
EncodingName      : OEM United States
HeaderName        : IBM437
WebName           : IBM437
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 437

Przelas
```

Comment: It seems `$OutputEncoding` in PowerShell is not correctly read by the cmdlet when using in non-interactive mode. I now did `[Console]::OutputEncoding :: [Text.Encoding]::UTF8; (Get-VMSwitch).Name` and it yielded the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar approach and just establish the code page for every command:

```
cmd := exec.Command("powershell.exe", "-c", "chcp", "65001", ">", "$null", ";", command)
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
```